# Deleting Multiple Progressive Files Using Command Line

Tags: command-line, removing

I have set of image files in a directory that I want to delete using command-line. The file names progress as follows:

```
image0000.png
....
image0599.png
```

I know we will need to use for-loop in the commmand-line but what would be the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to delete all the files in a directory with names like imageXXX.png, you won't have to use a for loop. You can use a wildcard like this `rm image*`.

**Note**-This will remove all the files in the current directory with names like imageXXXX

Comment: it worked! so assuming I would want to remove say only from image001 to image019, will I need for-loop then?